# PHP and Ajax using onchange event

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, select

I have the following Code in `cat.php` file:

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getsub.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$query = "SELECT cat from category GROUP BY cat";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<option value=''>".$row['cat']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

And after Calling the function - `getsub.php`

```
<?php
require_once('connect_db.php');
//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

$query = "SELECT sub from category WHERE cat = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result){
mysqli_error(); 
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<select name="sub">
<?php
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
echo "<option value='".$row['sub']."'>".$row['sub']."</option>";
}
?>
<select>

<?php
}
```

I'm looking forward to have a relation between Main Category and Sub Category. I want to Select the Main category and then calling the javascript function in order to show another select input for the Sub Category . The above code outputs nothing and I can't seem to find why?

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine. Try using the firebug extension for Firefox.
Open net panel in firebug and then see what data are you sending and what response in actually generating.
This will definitely help.
Also in cat.php, instead of using plain AJAX, try using jQuery as this will reduce large line of code as

```
// Just incude jQuery beforehand

script>
function showUser(str)
{
    $.get("getsub.php",{q:str},function(data){
        $("#txtHint).html(data);
   });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine but you have just a php tag in the end of the while loop that needs to be closed.